# Two separate UserControls seems to be the same instance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, instance

I'm having trouble with my user controls in WPF.

I have a Window, inside this window I have a custom menu (UserControl). In this menu, I have three CustomButtons. I also have, in the Window, a ContentControl that is used to show other UserControls that i'm using like pages. The buttons are used to select what page will be displayed.

Code:

```
<Local:CustomMenu x:Name="mainMenu" Margin="10,42,0,0" Height="39" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Local:CustomMenu.Items>
        <Local:CustomButton Text="Home" TextColor="Black" Click="cbHome_Click" />
        <Local:CustomButton Text="Users" TextColor="Black" Click="cbUsers_Click" />
        <Local:CustomButton Text="Options" TextColor="Black" Click="cbOptions_Click" />
    </Local:CustomMenu.Items>
</Local:CustomMenu >

<ContentControl x:Name="cControl" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,81,0,0" />
```

Example of a click:

```
private void cbOptions_Click(CustomButton arg1, RoutedEventArgs arg2)
{
    cControl.Content = new Options();
}
```

Into the "Options" page, I have another CustomMenu with four more CustomButtons, and also a ContentControl, to be like a subpage selection.

The problem starts here. When I select the Options page, an exception is raised in CustomMenu.xaml.cs when I put the Items of the CustomMenu inside a WrapPanel to show it.

Code:

```
foreach (FrameworkElement item in Items)
{
    myWrapPanel.Children.Add(item); // Exception here
}
```

The exception is: "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."

So I debuged it, and for my surprise, the CustomMenu inside the Options page has 7 items, and not 4 itens as expected.

But how if I add only four items to it? The three extra items are references to the first three buttons of the main window, thats why this exception is raised.

How it can be possible? Sorry if it was unclear.

Code of Options page:

```
<Local:CustomMenu x:Name="optionsMenu" Margin="10,42,0,0" Height="39" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Local:CustomMenu.Items>
        <Local:CustomButton Text="test" TextColor="Black" />
        <Local:CustomButton Text="test" TextColor="Black" />
        <Local:CustomButton Text="test" TextColor="Black" />
        <Local:CustomButton Text="test" TextColor="Black" />
    </Local:CustomMenu.Items>
</Local:CustomMenu >

<ContentControl x:Name="cControl" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,81,0,0" />
```

**EDIT**

Forcing the buttons to be placed into the CustomMenu, with the following code, only result into a more strange behaviour:

```
foreach (FrameworkElement item in Items)
{
    try 
    {
        myWrapPanel.Children.Add(item); 
    } 
    catch { }
}
```

The result is: 0 itens to the CustomMenu of the MainWindow (all itens disapeared), and the correct 4 itens for the CustomMenu in OptionsPage (at least).

**EDIT 2**

This is the definition of my items property, inside CustomMenu.xaml.cs:

```
public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<UIElement>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>),
typeof(CustomMenu), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<UIElement>()));
```

Comment: I have no idea how WPF works to be honest, but I would start from making sure the Items collection in the foreach statement is really the collection you want to iterate over. I also wonder if you really need to add these items to myWrapPanel's children as the exception seems to suggests otherwise. Just posting some ideas since no solution is coming up yet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm making the foreach because I'm using animations to show each button (I think that the complete code doesn't matter, but if you want to see, I put it here). The animations are like a fade in effect. I'll double-check the collection, but its strange anyway. There's two collections, one of 3 and one of 4 items... I'm trying to debug but it simply starts with 7 items.

Comment: Both ContentControls have the same name cControl. Are you maybe mixing names somewhere?

Comment: Please show the definition of your `Items` property.

Comment: @Nzc I've removed the ContentControl of the Options.xaml, but the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why you see seven items in your `CustomMenu` instead of four from the information that you have provided. That all sounds very strange. However, your problem that was caused by the following code...:

```
foreach (FrameworkElement item in Items)
{
    myWrapPanel.Children.Add(item); // Exception here
}
```

... is caused because, as the error says, the *Specified element is already the logical child of another element*. In WPF, UI elements can only appear once in the markup, so what that error means is that you can't add the UI items from the `Items` collection into another UI container control. Put more simply, you can't display those same items in more than one place at once. I can't tell exactly because we haven't seen the definition of your `CustomMenu` control.

You could move them from one container to another, but I fail to see why you are trying to do that anyway. In WPF, we generally manipulate the data, not the UI. So the WPF way to 'copy UI elements' would be to provide a `DataTemplate` to define the UI and then copy the data objects or just use a `Binding`.

Apologies if I have misunderstood you, but if I have, perhaps you could explain further (in an edit to your question) what the above code is for. You shouldn't need to use code like this, instead being able to `Bind` directly from inside your control to the `Items` property.